# Application for schengen visa. Proof of financial support

Tags: visas, schengen

I am planning to visit Europe in May 2017. One of the requirements in applying Schengen visa is the proof of financial support. I am currently working here in Dubai and my bank statement will come from my home country.

Will that be okay? Because I don't have savings account here in Dubai.

Comment: You have no bank account in Dubai? How are you paid?

Comment: Your circumstances - especially lack of bank account in Dubai - should be indeed explained in details in your visa application. Otherwise there is a good chance they'd assume you work in Dubai illegally. Never assume the Consulate will guess things in your favor.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing about your financial details are **regular income** and **regular, reasonable expenditures**. If you earn more than you spend, month after month for a long time, and if the cost of travel is a reasonable fraction of your annual income, things look good.